# How to supply parameters in Guice injections, while not breaking Guice-AOP method interception?

Tags: java, aop, guice, factory-pattern

I have a situation where I need to use Guice 3.0 to instantiate my object but one of the values will change potentially with each instance. I cannot bind that value's type and I won't know until I need to create the instance.

For instance:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {...}
}
```

I want Guice to inject the `Bar` param but I won't know `Baz` until I need `Foo`. The value isn't scope-specific (e.g. RequestScope) either.

The whole reason I want this object fully instantiated by Guice is because I need method interception. In Guice, "manually constructed instances do not participate in AOP".

I've tried to do this with `Provider<Foo>` but that only allows me `public Foo get() { ... }`.

It would be a configuration nightmare to have to create a provider for every possible value of `Baz`, so I can't simply have `Baz` be defined in FooProvider's constructor.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. Perhaps it is because it is the last thing I'm doing on a Friday. Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Edit:** The answer below to use "assisted injection" seems to only work if you have the ability to edit the source of `Foo`. `Foo` may actually be outside of my control for some instances. And if I create the instances myself (i.e., implement my own factory) then Guice-AOP method interceptors don't seem to ever know about the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like "assisted injection" might be a solution:

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html

Except it doesn't work if you don't have access to annotate the constructor of `Foo`.

**EDIT:** what I have found is that I am able to add the assisted injection annotations by extending the type and adding them to the constructor that I wish to use:

```
public class AssistedFoo extends Foo {
    @AssistedInject
    public AssistedFoo(
        Bar bar,
        @Assisted Baz baz) {
        super(bar, baz);
    }
}
```

Then use this extended implementation in the assisted injection registration:

```
public interface FooFactory {
    Foo create(Baz baz);
}

//...

install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(Foo.class, AssistedFoo.class)
    .build(FooFactory.class));
```

The extra inheritance class is only needed when you don't have access to change `Foo`. Obviously this workaround wouldn't work if the class is `final`.

Comment: What if I cannot add the `@Assisted` annotations to the `Baz` parameter(s)? e.g. for when I don't control the source of `Foo`.

Comment: Just write your own `FooFactory` class, inject `Bar` into it, and then have it expose a method that takes a `Baz` parameter. That method can then just `return new Foo(bar, baz)`. All Assisted Inject does (more or less) is save you from having to write that straightforward implementation.

Comment: That's actually back to what I started with but Guice won't allow method interceptors (Guice-AOP) on objects that it didn't create. Seems like I may have a situation where the limitations of two of their features conflict.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you may have.

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround you could try if you really need to get method interception working for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Assisted Inject to create the factory, you can just write your own factory implementation:

```
// same as for Assisted Inject
public interface FooFactory {
  Foo createFoo(Baz baz);
}

public class FooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory {
  private final Bar bar;

  @Inject
  public FooFactoryImpl(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public Foo createFoo(Baz baz) {
    return new Foo(bar, baz);
  }
}
```

Then just `bind(FooFactory.class).to(FooFactoryImpl.class)` and inject a `FooFactory` wherever you need to create `Foo`s.

**Edit:**

An exceedingly awkward workaround you could do (that would allow method interception on `Foo`):

- `bind(Foo.class).toConstructor(...)`
- Define and bind the `SimpleScope` scope described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes).
- `bind(Baz.class).in(BatchScoped.class)`
- Injected a `Provider<Foo>` and `SimpleScope` into the class that wants to create `Foo`s.

Then:

```
public Foo someMethod(Baz baz) {
  simpleScope.enter();
  try {
    simpleScope.seed(Baz.class, baz);
    /*
     * We're in the scope for Baz, so it can be injected normally into Foo
     * right now.
     */
    return fooProvider.get();
  } finally {
    scope.exit();
  }
}
```

You could even use method interception on such a method to handle the scoping, if the method isn't `private`... though it might not be a great idea since it would be confusing if you didn't use the parameter at all in the method but it had to be there to work.

Comment: Interesting use of scopes. Seems a little heavy and/or hard for others to follow. Shows that there might be an opportunity here for the Guice folks to add some mechanism.

Comment: @McKAMEY: Yeah, it's a pretty ugly hack I'd say! I think a preferable solution would be to just live with not being able to use method interception on `Foo`. One option there might be to create your own (interceptable and Assisted Injectable) class to wrap `Foo` and expose the methods you need on it.

Comment: if you check out the other answer I was able to get assisted injection working via inhering from `Foo`. That allows me to control the constructor annotations.

Comment: @McKAMEY: Yep, that would be a good solution for any class that you can extend.